# iphone beginner : Cannot figure out where the leak is

Tags: iphone, uiview, uilabel, memory-leaks, instruments

I am trying to get my hands on some iphone development. To try to better understand things, I'm going first without IB.

I managed to build a basic app that displays some text. No big deal, until I ran it through Instruments. It shows me some leaks and I cannot understand them.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**MyAppDelegate.h**

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow            *window;
    MyViewController    *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)  IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  MyViewController *viewController;

@end
```

**MyAppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    // NEXT LINE LEAKS   
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

**MyViewController.h**

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel     *firstMessage;
}
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
-(void)loadView {

    // Background
    CGRect mainFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mainFrame];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.view = contentView;
    [contentView release];

    // Add UILabel
    // NEXT LINE LEAKS   
    firstMessage = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 30)];
    firstMessage.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
    firstMessage.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    firstMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    [self.view addSubview:firstMessage];
    [firstMessage release];
 }

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    NSString * msg;
    msg=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"stuff here"];
    firstMessage.text=msg;
    [msg release];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [firstMessage release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: what is in your viewcontrollers dealloc?

Comment: there are no leaks in this code. Probably leaks in some other part of code that you didn't post. BTW,  MyViewController    *viewController; in declaration  and   @property (nonatomic, retain)  BouncersViewController *viewController;   in property. Correct this.

Comment: OK fixed this. I really commented out all other code, so it really doesn't do more. Nevertheless, I'll setup a new project with just what I wrote above and run it again through instruments. Looks silly, and I really shouldn't worry about it (it works), but I guess if I don't understand it, I have no chance to figure out real complex leaks.

Comment: Added the dealloc method

Comment: now you are over releasing your firstMessage, because you added the object to subview, your firstMessage will be released when the view is gone so you don't have to release it again in the dealloc

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel* firstMessage` in your header, `@synthesize firstMessage` in your implementation and then release your firstMessage object in the dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to release your firstMessage in loadView. Only release it in your controller's dealloc method.

Comment: then it definitely would be a leak in case of memory warning. There are no leaks in that code.

Comment: I'm concerned about your code because your controller releases  firstMessage in loadView but then expects it to be present in viewDidLoad.

Comment: So what? The retain count is 1. And when that label is removed from the superview it would be properly deallocated.

Comment: If it works, great. To me, it just looks like you're releasing prematurely. But I may be wrong.

Comment: About Dimitri's comment : I agree, I felt uncomfortable releasing firstmessage in LoadView. But I kind of felt compelled to do so with all the examples I found on the web :-). Anyway, releasing it or not didn't seem to affect the leak detected by Instruments. But then, my real question is : is that the good way to manipulate my UILabels? I found other ways like tagging the UILabel when you create it, release it, then later, when you need it, retrieve it by its tag but it seems quite heavy...